# Installing eclypse plugin into flash builder 4.6

Tags: eclipse, flash, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I am running the stand alone version of Flash builder. what I am wanting to do is to install an eclipse plugin into it. Is this possible or is it only possible if I install flash builder as an eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can install eclipse plugins into Flash Builder 4.6. The download system works exactly like Eclipse Indigo (which I believe Builder is built upon). This means you can install new software and go to the various Marketplaces in order to get software to download. Everything works exactly as t would with a "regular" eclipse installation (including the annoying dependency messages, which you will tend to get more of because Builder is not a complete Eclipse implementation!).

It does work, though.